# Gradle build profiles for i18n and PrettyFaces

Tags: internationalization, gradle, prettyfaces

Is it possible to define different profiles in gradle? I've written a WebApplication and i want to deploy it with the production settings. Furthermore my app is using PrettyFaces. Since i'm using different two languages i also want a language sepcific build. Here is my use case:
production/en, production/ru

The build with a specific language indicates which db to use and which language is the default one. Furthermore the urls (PrettyFaces) are different files. In my opinion i need a different web.xml and a different pretty-faces.xml ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some options:

1. Create a task for each setting, so you can do `gradle buildEn` or `gradle buildRu` to differentiate the builds. You can write each task manually, or [dynamically generate them](http://gradle.org/current/docs/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#N1028A).
2. Pass a project property to your build, e.g. `gradle build -Plang=ru`. Then you can reference `lang` from your task and do the logic there. Project properties can also be specified in `gradle.properties` file if you don't like passing the property every time. [Anyway check this out.](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/09/gradle-goodness-different-ways-to-set.html)
3. Probably not what you want, but you can add behaviour to your build if a certain [task is present in the build graph](http://evgeny-goldin.com/wiki/Gradle#Setting_the_repository_URL_at_the_time_the_DAG_is_ready) (in the example additional logic is executed when graph contains `release` task).

Good luck